# R - Color or shade area between lines

Tags: r, xts, lattice, confidence-interval, timeserieschart

I'm trying to replicate with R a chart I made on Excel, which should represent a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) around a time series forecast. The Excel chart looks like this:

[image]

So, basically, the original historical time series and from a certain point in time the forecast of what it could be with its respective CI.

They way it's done on Excel is a bit inefficient:

1. I have four time series which overlap much of the time;
2. The actual/historical time series (blue line above) simply stops when the forecast begins;
3. The forecast (dotted red above) is simply hidden below the blue one until the forecast period begins;
4. Then I have a time series representing the difference between the the upper bound and the lower bound of the CI, which playing around with Excel Stacked Areas charts, becomes the shaded area in the chart above.

Obviously, the computation to generate the forecast and the CIs is much faster and easier to generalize and use with R, and while I could complete the task on R and then simply copy the output on Excel to draw the chart, doing everything in R would be much nicer.

**At the end of the question I provided the raw data with `dput()` as suggested by @MLavoie.**

Here the packages I loaded (not sure you need them all here, but they are the ones I usually work with):

```
    require(zoo)
    require(xts)
    require(lattice)
    require(latticeExtra)
```

My data looks like this for the first 100 rows:

```
    > head(data)
               fifth_percentile   Median nintyfifth_percentile
    2017-06-18         1.146267 1.146267              1.146267
    2017-06-19         1.134643 1.134643              1.134643
    2017-06-20         1.125664 1.125664              1.125664
    2017-06-21         1.129037 1.129037              1.129037
    2017-06-22         1.147542 1.147542              1.147542
    2017-06-23         1.159989 1.159989              1.159989
```

Then after the 100 data point, the time series start to diverge and at the end they look like this:

```
    > tail(data)
               fifth_percentile   Median nintyfifth_percentile
    2017-12-30        0.9430930 1.125844              1.341603
    2017-12-31        0.9435227 1.127391              1.354928
    2018-01-01        0.9417235 1.124625              1.355527
    2018-01-02        0.9470077 1.124088              1.361420
    2018-01-03        0.9571596 1.127299              1.364005
    2018-01-04        0.9515535 1.127978              1.369536
```

**Solution provided by DaveTurek**

Thanks to DaveTurek I've found the answer. However, only difference is that for my xts dataframe, apparently, I need first to convert each column to numbers (with `as.numeric()`). No idea if that stems from me doing something wrong with xts and lattice, or it is the only way to achieve it using DaveTurek suggestion. Will try to investigate it further.

Here is the code to generate the chart:

```
    x = index(data[1:100,2])
    y = as.numeric(data[1:100,2])
    ex.x = index(data[101:200,2])
    ex.y = as.numeric(data[101:200,2])
    ex.lo = as.numeric(data[101:200,1])
    ex.hi = as.numeric(data[101:200,3])

    xyplot(y~x, ylim = c(0.9,1.4),
   panel=function(x,y,...) {
     panel.lines(x,y,lwd=2,col=4)
     panel.polygon(c(ex.x,rev(ex.x)),c(ex.lo,rev(ex.hi)),border=NA,col=5)
     panel.lines(ex.x,ex.y,lwd=2,col=2)
   })
```

And here the final result:

[image]

Here is the final dataset, from dput(), that I'm trying to plot:

```
    > dput(data)
    structure(c(1.14626724930899, 1.13464279067717, 1.12566420479952, 
    1.12903662366847, 1.14754211999921, 1.15998855701439, 1.15274364578958, 
    1.16226441955745, 1.16169992687419, 1.16520028734587, 1.16823402018407, 
    1.19832130049664, 1.18411773220697, 1.18531274215286, 1.16421444455115, 
    1.17108139956539, 1.18392357740377, 1.20103911352579, 1.17791736605905, 
    1.18277944964829, 1.20162550199013, 1.19665058179752, 1.19411188122108, 
    1.19367558590966, 1.19803272562951, 1.20600155861871, 1.22189449901607, 
    1.22072774140118, 1.22312376195254, 1.25355505518571, 1.25895911759195, 
    1.2613354420716, 1.24440525381363, 1.24444079462029, 1.24168652168112, 
    1.24154936710117, 1.23440527301777, 1.22592718438811, 1.21709102449773, 
    1.21448030929365, 1.23109601090898, 1.24401127451953, 1.23953314346685, 
    1.21863565024168, 1.20834325548551, 1.20281193695583, 1.20405850724191, 
    1.19608032796923, 1.22008184095742, 1.21675995421116, 1.20198916403093, 
    1.20029121301547, 1.18822375424598, 1.19007923345344, 1.19285965857709, 
    1.1971013197471, 1.1776860331227, 1.18028531916998, 1.18394951589397, 
    1.16712430930941, 1.17827461393349, 1.18751430033172, 1.21482260909863, 
    1.2167262724184, 1.21729489152574, 1.21847062594996, 1.21932070698031, 
    1.19678189566773, 1.17678214957629, 1.17586968485613, 1.16903708967946, 
    1.16967697995898, 1.14498266161799, 1.12782282645368, 1.11540004479973, 
    1.12639853863918, 1.11402516325222, 1.10511837662567, 1.10600107687395, 
    1.10243149863659, 1.10404564773364, 1.12949458422398, 1.11679224666313, 
    1.11338078540871, 1.10762728498848, 1.12437898939299, 1.11572706259347, 
    1.1148111967932, 1.12358625045939, 1.11169207274881, 1.13009253108247, 
    1.13772927166761, 1.12550770863279, 1.13062401691547, 1.12821231512428, 
    1.13174620070443, 1.13072790983063, 1.1428325334377, 1.12739171867048,
    1.1214997813059, 1.11870510839984, 1.096148222775, 1.08805136310032, 
    1.08701594286129, 1.08047984136855, 1.07939438148434, 1.0684082570972, 
    1.06497159411023, 1.05820047926833, 1.06322519359802, 1.06234781015662, 
    1.05431808916504, 1.054405104791, 1.05330182895869, 1.04787681441803, 
    1.041698698458, 1.03870702538097, 1.03300007904201, 1.02741553353049, 
    1.03525701392318, 1.0339774223954, 1.0328464056954, 1.03100871401712, 
    1.03348765946373, 1.03473218333386, 1.02942612874379, 1.02109481188296, 
    1.02301597272716, 1.01553904377803, 1.0031650628692, 1.00779708136199, 
    1.01322764666693, 1.01964272925677, 1.02125480865504, 1.02300342204156, 
    1.02563993245866, 1.02972111884963, 1.02048756192688, 1.00481457379443, 
    1.00512607721887, 1.01094340128446, 1.01377432300649, 1.01170553705668, 
    1.00551128145228, 1.00612634442438, 1.00735643866839, 1.0080606590012, 
    0.985706701720841, 0.982234200010558, 0.975314534071082, 0.973611418201841, 
    0.968118612511537, 0.973092829667201, 0.975599110408158, 0.967214930243667, 
    0.968569928969912, 0.963572085616274, 0.964901787179726, 0.957782708788541, 
    0.951868416101986, 0.956694066411684, 0.956937537219092, 0.956303331651844, 
    0.947880835881923, 0.956308493824626, 0.948146077843001, 0.945939091828748, 
    0.945082701640947, 0.937222489932819, 0.937989843132858, 0.948712728941467, 
    0.939050882255992, 0.946264846068344, 0.944926693194716, 0.946825914432391, 
    0.939070104432721, 0.950666108330947, 0.949365988007735, 0.943616625744159, 
    0.946600795357699, 0.941276090147603, 0.939957902451166, 0.941523527816784, 
    0.946611480333791, 0.959236316317354, 0.96165367272139, 0.957508302724503, 
    0.954774123925477, 0.960811125123549, 0.956525507301749, 0.948237690612711, 
    0.951299123137395, 0.945212566792479, 0.94507842203255, 0.942735006048921, 
    0.943093032220433, 0.943522672031737, 0.941723495992432, 0.947007713852018, 
    0.95715960245335, 0.951553478810637, 1.14626724930899, 1.13464279067717, 
    1.12566420479952, 1.12903662366847, 1.14754211999921, 1.15998855701439, 
    1.15274364578958, 1.16226441955745, 1.16169992687419, 1.16520028734587, 
    1.16823402018407, 1.19832130049664, 1.18411773220697, 1.18531274215286, 
    1.16421444455115, 1.17108139956539, 1.18392357740377, 1.20103911352579, 
    1.17791736605905, 1.18277944964829, 1.20162550199013, 1.19665058179752, 
    1.19411188122108, 1.19367558590966, 1.19803272562951, 1.20600155861871, 
    1.22189449901607, 1.22072774140118, 1.22312376195254, 1.25355505518571, 
    1.25895911759195, 1.2613354420716, 1.24440525381363, 1.24444079462029, 
    1.24168652168112, 1.24154936710117, 1.23440527301777, 1.22592718438811, 
    1.21709102449773, 1.21448030929365, 1.23109601090898, 1.24401127451953, 
    1.23953314346685, 1.21863565024168, 1.20834325548551, 1.20281193695583, 
    1.20405850724191, 1.19608032796923, 1.22008184095742, 1.21675995421116, 
    1.20198916403093, 1.20029121301547, 1.18822375424598, 1.19007923345344, 
    1.19285965857709, 1.1971013197471, 1.1776860331227, 1.18028531916998, 
    1.18394951589397, 1.16712430930941, 1.17827461393349, 1.18751430033172, 
    1.21482260909863, 1.2167262724184, 1.21729489152574, 1.21847062594996, 
    1.21932070698031, 1.19678189566773, 1.17678214957629, 1.17586968485613, 
    1.16903708967946, 1.16967697995898, 1.14498266161799, 1.12782282645368, 
    1.11540004479973, 1.12639853863918, 1.11402516325222, 1.10511837662567, 
    1.10600107687395, 1.10243149863659, 1.10404564773364, 1.12949458422398, 
    1.11679224666313, 1.11338078540871, 1.10762728498848, 1.12437898939299, 
    1.11572706259347, 1.1148111967932, 1.12358625045939, 1.11169207274881, 
    1.13009253108247, 1.13772927166761, 1.12550770863279, 1.13062401691547, 
    1.12821231512428, 1.13174620070443, 1.13072790983063, 1.1428325334377, 
    1.12739171867048, 1.1214997813059, 1.11870510839984, 1.11811303551412, 
    1.11855383782522, 1.11981261957516, 1.12096887905804, 1.12162710713999, 
    1.12015553029278, 1.12189306008921, 1.1236834173899, 1.12204149206779, 
    1.12075809542535, 1.12116672935174, 1.12216772364685, 1.11821915571021, 
    1.12117719223463, 1.11896003906963, 1.11563621625852, 1.1183625095638, 
    1.12053072892388, 1.1216348268255, 1.12317377733957, 1.11873136428952, 
    1.12267083202989, 1.12642930089215, 1.13027646770951, 1.13129632891931, 
    1.12700346009603, 1.12060488827701, 1.12390899402613, 1.13129350591169, 
    1.12786650327192, 1.1274201121913, 1.13101906643359, 1.12727135093377, 
    1.12458327192256, 1.12259738972645, 1.12097982776572, 1.12073621452193, 
    1.12364872830763, 1.12644326299714, 1.12556263098661, 1.12797963752343, 
    1.12734519199847, 1.1261793072762, 1.12911407446825, 1.12754878937943, 
    1.12777579027467, 1.12554965831588, 1.12324469267853, 1.12231558194992, 
    1.12135908710208, 1.11923353817423, 1.12345300992675, 1.12186883237389, 
    1.12173652640663, 1.12488148969114, 1.12664301925369, 1.12294230775256, 
    1.12393650688095, 1.13038044949978, 1.12822226676967, 1.12934384230215, 
    1.1217648908055, 1.12218158739803, 1.12302651609468, 1.12682187689922, 
    1.13537701046932, 1.13172108462183, 1.1374053505525, 1.13498257452656, 
    1.12692005654471, 1.13210629725645, 1.12868775509168, 1.13073909215368, 
    1.13098804355869, 1.13353301668386, 1.13336476594698, 1.13233873705211, 
    1.12667020676157, 1.12133152301322, 1.12418759586717, 1.12048022460741, 
    1.12798162212357, 1.13053093896994, 1.12019367019997, 1.12422483586498, 
    1.11303086301782, 1.11986711815552, 1.12504718249418, 1.11341517044014, 
    1.12495096618792, 1.12995127061511, 1.13538401552385, 1.13145536081928, 
    1.1264465959783, 1.12584386458867, 1.1273908895838, 1.12462482614994, 
    1.1240880626286, 1.12729907535003, 1.12797751377714, 1.14626724930899, 
    1.13464279067717, 1.12566420479952, 1.12903662366847, 1.14754211999921, 
    1.15998855701439, 1.15274364578958, 1.16226441955745, 1.16169992687419, 
    1.16520028734587, 1.16823402018407, 1.19832130049664, 1.18411773220697, 
    1.18531274215286, 1.16421444455115, 1.17108139956539, 1.18392357740377, 
    1.20103911352579, 1.17791736605905, 1.18277944964829, 1.20162550199013, 
    1.19665058179752, 1.19411188122108, 1.19367558590966, 1.19803272562951, 
    1.20600155861871, 1.22189449901607, 1.22072774140118, 1.22312376195254, 
    1.25355505518571, 1.25895911759195, 1.2613354420716, 1.24440525381363, 
    1.24444079462029, 1.24168652168112, 1.24154936710117, 1.23440527301777, 
    1.22592718438811, 1.21709102449773, 1.21448030929365, 1.23109601090898, 
    1.24401127451953, 1.23953314346685, 1.21863565024168, 1.20834325548551, 
    1.20281193695583, 1.20405850724191, 1.19608032796923, 1.22008184095742, 
    1.21675995421116, 1.20198916403093, 1.20029121301547, 1.18822375424598, 
    1.19007923345344, 1.19285965857709, 1.1971013197471, 1.1776860331227, 
    1.18028531916998, 1.18394951589397, 1.16712430930941, 1.17827461393349, 
    1.18751430033172, 1.21482260909863, 1.2167262724184, 1.21729489152574, 
    1.21847062594996, 1.21932070698031, 1.19678189566773, 1.17678214957629, 
    1.17586968485613, 1.16903708967946, 1.16967697995898, 1.14498266161799, 
    1.12782282645368, 1.11540004479973, 1.12639853863918, 1.11402516325222, 
    1.10511837662567, 1.10600107687395, 1.10243149863659, 1.10404564773364, 
    1.12949458422398, 1.11679224666313, 1.11338078540871, 1.10762728498848, 
    1.12437898939299, 1.11572706259347, 1.1148111967932, 1.12358625045939, 
    1.11169207274881, 1.13009253108247, 1.13772927166761, 1.12550770863279, 
    1.13062401691547, 1.12821231512428, 1.13174620070443, 1.13072790983063, 
    1.1428325334377, 1.12739171867048, 1.1214997813059, 1.11870510839984, 
    1.14162401974592, 1.15630966411729, 1.15992199767135, 1.16683144867851, 
    1.16928280999155, 1.17287782220285, 1.18184525262982, 1.17555305757354, 
    1.18031492211593, 1.18142628277888, 1.18307577052783, 1.18257404220722, 
    1.19421117710041, 1.19403330560815, 1.19510080390052, 1.2058940348108, 
    1.19848571699109, 1.20138771250604, 1.20660682710938, 1.20790011589089, 
    1.20963951875753, 1.21572259411602, 1.21379678812156, 1.220302087399, 
    1.22062959185172, 1.22743877731977, 1.23135277550334, 1.24075667733246, 
    1.24169498945046, 1.23529301399753, 1.2399941777708, 1.24823732280171, 
    1.23861121958778, 1.24816319854615, 1.25252933549084, 1.25133386983018, 
    1.24512546001264, 1.2617641352045, 1.25486018976211, 1.25424601859098, 
    1.25820538036104, 1.25968528498312, 1.26939611029084, 1.27883933177157, 
    1.27926882841012, 1.27951234203094, 1.28997494816278, 1.29391898267335, 
    1.2971442938215, 1.29733541086814, 1.30376525837809, 1.31025722802128, 
    1.29718190520268, 1.27919305871102, 1.28685138548374, 1.28594279969497, 
    1.28695233433419, 1.30277136510213, 1.29178316107299, 1.29586799884087, 
    1.30076586308517, 1.30881154838964, 1.32171887794143, 1.3197588324899, 
    1.3121332301804, 1.31744410759858, 1.31402945919721, 1.30926303329755, 
    1.32019231597949, 1.31449633135152, 1.31730801686101, 1.31834557852015, 
    1.3175761022299, 1.33430488507454, 1.34091614601639, 1.33606628597812, 
    1.33180446732765, 1.33630738683041, 1.33449101077219, 1.32521028784732, 
    1.32241490851887, 1.31488015995544, 1.31913131799656, 1.32901121011698, 
    1.33177659436063, 1.32577077582349, 1.31960627618725, 1.31307169067904, 
    1.32148403094167, 1.33104893196281, 1.33491831741272, 1.3386091981919, 
    1.35730874062825, 1.3460340606746, 1.34160318929376, 1.35492848895938, 
    1.35552729646417, 1.36141957863605, 1.36400538435282, 1.369536167295),
    .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC",
    class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1497744000, 1497830400, 1497916800, 
    1498003200, 1498089600, 1498176000, 1498262400, 1498348800, 1498435200, 
    1498521600, 1498608000, 1498694400, 1498780800, 1498867200, 1498953600, 
    1499040000, 1499126400, 1499212800, 1499299200, 1499385600, 1499472000, 
    1499558400, 1499644800, 1499731200, 1499817600, 1499904000, 1499990400, 
    1500076800, 1500163200, 1500249600, 1500336000, 1500422400, 1500508800, 
    1500595200, 1500681600, 1500768000, 1500854400, 1500940800, 1501027200, 
    1501113600, 1501200000, 1501286400, 1501372800, 1501459200, 1501545600, 
    1501632000, 1501718400, 1501804800, 1501891200, 1501977600, 1502064000, 
    1502150400, 1502236800, 1502323200, 1502409600, 1502496000, 1502582400, 
    1502668800, 1502755200, 1502841600, 1502928000, 1503014400, 1503100800, 
    1503187200, 1503273600, 1503360000, 1503446400, 1503532800, 1503619200, 
    1503705600, 1503792000, 1503878400, 1503964800, 1504051200, 1504137600, 
    1504224000, 1504310400, 1504396800, 1504483200, 1504569600, 1504656000, 
    1504742400, 1504828800, 1504915200, 1505001600, 1505088000, 1505174400, 
    1505260800, 1505347200, 1505433600, 1505520000, 1505606400, 1505692800, 
    1505779200, 1505865600, 1505952000, 1506038400, 1506124800, 1506211200, 
    1506297600, 1506384000, 1506470400, 1506556800, 1506643200, 1506729600, 
    1506816000, 1506902400, 1506988800, 1507075200, 1507161600, 1507248000, 
    1507334400, 1507420800, 1507507200, 1507593600, 1507680000, 1507766400, 
    1507852800, 1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 
    1508371200, 1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 
    1508889600, 1508976000, 1509062400, 1509148800, 1509235200, 1509321600, 
    1509408000, 1509494400, 1509580800, 1509667200, 1509753600, 1509840000, 
    1509926400, 1510012800, 1510099200, 1510185600, 1510272000, 1510358400, 
    1510444800, 1510531200, 1510617600, 1510704000, 1510790400, 1510876800, 
    1510963200, 1511049600, 1511136000, 1511222400, 1511308800, 1511395200, 
    1511481600, 1511568000, 1511654400, 1511740800, 1511827200, 1511913600, 
    1.512e+09, 1512086400, 1512172800, 1512259200, 1512345600, 1512432000, 
    1512518400, 1512604800, 1512691200, 1512777600, 1512864000, 1512950400, 
    1513036800, 1513123200, 1513209600, 1513296000, 1513382400, 1513468800, 
    1513555200, 1513641600, 1513728000, 1513814400, 1513900800, 1513987200, 
    1514073600, 1514160000, 1514246400, 1514332800, 1514419200, 1514505600, 
    1514592000, 1514678400, 1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000
    ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(201L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("fifth_percentile", "Median", "nintyfifth_percentile"
)))
```

Comment: you should use dput() to make your dataset available. Just run dput(namedataset) in R

Comment: This is generally a good question, but (1) can you make it [reproducible](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) (2) can you split into two questions (e.g. delete the part about changing the axis font and ask it as a separate question)?

Comment: Will make it reproducible tomorrow morning as soon as I can work on it! Deleted part 2 regarding the axis font.Thanks for the tips/answers.

Comment: Thanks @DaveTurek ! Will try it on my data as soon as I can, unfortunately won't be before late tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried with your data, but if the question is how to shade the forecast area, maybe this simple example will help.

```
library(lattice)

x = 1:12 # base data
y = x
ex.x = 12:16 # extrapolated data
ex.y = 12:16
ex.lo = 12+0:4*.3 # lower bound
ex.hi = 12+0:4*1.6 # upper bound

xyplot(y~x,xlim=c(0:18),ylim=c(0:20),
  panel=function(x,y,...) {
    panel.lines(x,y,lwd=2,col=4)
    panel.polygon(c(ex.x,rev(ex.x)),c(ex.lo,rev(ex.hi)),border=NA,col=5)
    panel.lines(ex.x,ex.y,lwd=2,col=2)
})
```

You can add the shaded polygon to the lattice plot in a panel function.  I used `c(ex.x,rev(ex.x))` and `c(ex.lo,rev(ex.hi))` to construct the polygon boundary.

Comment: Thanks @DaveTurek, your solution worked perfectly. Only thing for my xts object I had to convert it to numbers first. Question updated and solved!